# Multiple integration with functions of variables in the limits

Tags: r, integral

I need to numerically integrate the following:

[image]

I tried to use `cubature` and `pracma` but they don't seem to support functional integration limits. I found a attempt to use `cubature` by:

```
library(cubature)

integrand <- function(arg) {
   x <- arg[1]
   y <- arg[2]
   z <- arg[3]
   w <- arg[4]
   v<- arg[5]
   ff <- dnorm(x, 10,2)*dnorm(y, 10,2)*dnorm(z, 10,2)*dnorm(w, 10,2)* dnorm(v, 10,2)* (x+y+z+w+v<=52)
   return(ff)
}

R <- cuhre(f = integrand, 
           lowerLimit=c(0,0,0,0,0), 
           upperLimit=c(20,20,20,20,20), 
           relTol = 1e-5, absTol= 1e-5)
```

But the author doesn't guarantee that it's correct to do it.

Is there a way to numerically integrate multiple integrals with functional limits in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain of integration is the canonical simplex scaled by the factor 42. To evaluate an integral on a simplex, use the `SimplicialCubature` package:

```
integrand <- function(arg) {
  x <- arg[1]
  y <- arg[2]
  z <- arg[3]
  w <- arg[4]
  v <- arg[5]
  dnorm(x, 10, 2) * 
    dnorm(y, 10, 2) * 
    dnorm(z, 10, 2) * 
    dnorm(w, 10, 2) * 
    dnorm(v, 10, 2)
}

library(SimplicialCubature)
Simplex <- 42 * CanonicalSimplex(5)
```

Here is the command to run:

```
adaptIntegrateSimplex(integrand, S = Simplex)
# $integral
# [1] 0.03252553
# 
# $estAbsError
# [1] 0.3248119
# 
# $functionEvaluations
# [1] 9792
# 
# $returnCode
# [1] 1
# 
# $message
# [1] "error: maxEvals exceeded - too many function evaluations"
```

The algorithm has reached the maximal number of function evaluations and the estimated absolute error is `0.3248119`, while the estimated value of the integral is `0.03252553`. This is a big error.

We can increase the maximum number of function evaluations allowed. Taking `1e6`, the computation is a bit slow and we get:

```
adaptIntegrateSimplex(integrand, S = Simplex, maxEvals = 1e6)
# $integral
# [1] 0.03682535
# 
# $estAbsError
# [1] 0.001004083
# 
# $functionEvaluations
# [1] 999811
# 
# $returnCode
# [1] 1
# 
# $message
# [1] "error: maxEvals exceeded - too many function evaluations"
```

The estimated error has decreased to `0.001004083`, quite better.

Note that we can approximate this integral by using simulations, because this integral is the measure of the simplex under a multivariate normal distribution:

```
library(mvtnorm)
Sigma <- 2^2 * diag(5)
Mean <- rep(10, 5)
set.seed(666)
sims <- rmvnorm(1e6, mean = Mean, sigma = Sigma)

f <- function(X){ # test whether 0 < x < 42, 0 < x + y < 42, 0 < x + y + z < 42, ...
  all(X > 0 & cumsum(X) < 42)
}

mean(apply(sims, 1, f))
# 0.037083
```